# How to check CMD+CLICK

Tags: jquery

In the snippet below, if a do "CMD+CLICK" on link, it doesn't show `alert('CMD')`. Why is that?

I want to do something when user press CMD button (or CTRL key on windows) + click on href, how can I implement that?

```js
jQuery("#links").bind("click", function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey)
        alert('cmd');
    
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('click');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='links'>
    <a href="//google.com/">Google.com</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The apple cmd key is called a meta key in javascript events, so

```
if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey){
  alert('cmd');
}
```

should work.

[event.metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.metaKey)